# Loading Data error when

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

I use DSX model builder to load data and train the model. It was working fine with both auto and manual modes until early this month.

The issue is I am now not able to load the data which is a simple csv file on Object Store. That is the same file I used before.

I know other people can use the model builder without issues. Is this related to the recent upgrade or this is only for my environment?

Please see attached screenshots:

```
[select auto model to prepare and train the model][1]
[select the dataset][2]
[receive a data loading error][3]
```

Answer (score 0):

There can multiple problems underneath.
But WML model on DSX is associated with spark service and watson machine learning service from bluemix.
The problem is likely to be around this two services.
Easiest way to workaround would be to create another spark service if you are using Free spark service and then try to re-associate your model with this new spark service.

Edit the model -> click i and then select this new spark service that you added to your project and click update.

If this system wide spark related issue then you need to wait IBM spark service team to fix it.
I would suggest to reach out to ibm support for above in case it doesn't help.

Thanks,
Charles.